# Create new classes in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel framework.

I have a question regarding classes creation.
To explain my question, i will give you an example:

```
class articleController extends Controller{
    public function bla(){
        $a = new MyNewClass($colorfulVariable);
        $b = $a->createSomething(new MySecondNewClass());
    }
}
```

Now, the classes `MyNewClass` and `MySecondNewClass` do not exist, I want to create them, use them in every controller I want, just like I use the Redirect or Request classes that `Laravel` offers.

How can i create this classes? Make a new functions to use them in my laravel project?

Comment: Hi Itzhak, you can't use a clases without create them before. Please, give more details about your question. Regards!

Comment: This is only an example code. This classes not really exists, i just asked when can i create them and how can i use them?

Comment: Now I understand you. As wezzy says, any class in the App folder is loaded, but remember set the correct namespace to each new class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can just create those classes in your app folder (or in subfolder for example we create a Libraries folder with all the utilities). Just include a use App\YourClass; before using those classes and laravel will include the classes for you

Comment: Just to create a folder and include the classes? laravel did not create wonderful option to manage easily new libraries or classes?

Comment: If you want to use 3d party libraries you can use composer. But if you want to create custom classes just for your project the fastest way is to just create your classes in the app folder

Comment: And i have to include them into the composer.json file like @Alexey Mezenin said in his comment?

Comment: It's not necessary in my composer.json i have this lines:         "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }, so everything under app is already loaded automatically. You just have to tell laravel to use those classes using "use"

Answer (score 4):

Laravel 5.* is autoloaded using PSR-4, within the app/ directory. You can see this in the composer.json file.

```
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Basically, you could create another directory within app, and then namespace your files in there as appropriate:

```
app/folder1/folder2/SomeClass.php.
```

Then, within your SomeClass.php, make sure you namespace it:

```
<?php namespace App\folder1\folder2;

class Someclass {}
```

Now, you can access this class using the namespace within your classes:

```
use App\folder1\folder2\SomeClass;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your classes as usual, but don't forget to include them into `composer.json` autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "App\MyClassesNamespace"
....
```

And then run `composer dumpauto` command to rebuild autoloader file. If you'll not do this, you'll not be able to use your classes in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything other than below things:

1. Create a class in App\ folder.
2. Whenever you use the class, you will have to import the class using "use App\XYZ;" on top of the importing class.

thats it. Mostly people follow convention and then create "Service" folder on App\ folder. It is good to create alien class into service folder which are other than laravel framework classes.